# Android TableLayout resizing its width from fill_parent to wrap_content itself

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have several TableLayout's that have layout_width="fill_parent" but sometimes they seem to switch to layout_width="wrap_content" on their own, causing the entire table to squeeze and fit in minimum width.

One of the affected tables is:

```
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tbl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
<TableRow>
<Button
 android:id="@+id/btn1"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:text="@string/btn1"
 android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_input_get" 
/>
<Button 
 android:id="@+id/btn2"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:text="@string/btn2"
 android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode_off" 
/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

As you can see, pretty standard stuff. It starts off looking right, but if I navigate away from the Activity and come back, the switch seems to happen randomly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following properties:

- android:collapseColumns
- android:shrinkColumns
- android:stretchColumns

To know more, check [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Comment: The table is using android:stretchColumns="*"